# Very low heat weight of my model after auto weight

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I am using Blender 2.90 version, and I am in the part of adding armature. I create a "Human (Meta-rig)" than I use "armature deform with automatic weights". But when I making the pose, it seems that the auto weight doesn't work... please tell me how do I fix it?

[image: 1]]
[image: 2]]
[image: 3]]

Answer (score 0):

If a bone doesn't have full control over part of your mesh, another bone is partially influencing it. Make sure the beginning and end of each bone are touching the mesh, so the automatic weighting works better.

In your screenshot it looks like bones from the left leg are influencing the right leg and vice versa. To get rid of this effect select the left leg in Edit Mode (e.g. go to wireframe, Box select the vertices from the left leg) and then remove the weight from any bone in the right leg or assign it a value of 0. Then repeat the other way around. (I recommend using "Remove")

[image: Vertex Weight]

Comment: I tried what you said, but nothing seems to improve. After I opened the early file, this problem did not happen again, but I still don’t know what caused it. btw, thank you for answering my question.